# Нет ref-ссылки на компонент, переданный в слоте дочернего компонента

Tags: vue.js, компоненты

Для меня стало открытием то, что я не могу достучаться к `ref` в компоненте, который определил как слот для дочернего компонента.

Вот пример:

```
<template>
  <header ref=“header”>
    <logo ref=“logo”></logo>
  </header>
</template>
```

В компоненте `Header.vue` внутри определен просто дефолтный `<slot></slot>`.

И проблема в том, что к компоненту `Logo.vue` я достучаться из своего компонента не могу.

Ни через `this.$refs[‘logo’]`, ни через `this.$refs[‘header’].$refs[‘logo’]`. Ни через слоты компонента `Header.vue`. Никак...

Скажите, как быть.

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно новичок в vue, но мало ли поможет
Я к слотам обращаюсь внутри родительского тега(у вас header) таким образом:

```
<template v-slot:no-data>
    <v-btn @click="initialize">Refresh</v-btn>
</template>
```

Comment: Не, это не о том вообще. Тут ты просто имя дал слоту.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете Vue2 то просто забудьте про доступ к компонентам через слоты - оно того не стоит. В Vue3 вам может помочь $slots и $scopedSlots.

Comment: пример, вероятно, совсем не помешал бы.